# Can we Use Ajax DLL 3.5 in 2.0 Framework

Tags: dll, asp.net-ajax, assemblies

I want to use the ajax dll 3.5 in the website of framework 2.0
so is this possible by adding assembly or any other ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3.5 assemblies for your 2.0 projects as they all run on CLR v2, but I would probably advise you not to.

You should either live with the 2.0 version og upgrade to 3.5 (and install it on the server hosting the app).

With that being said it might run though, unless you run into issues with deployment to non 3.5 environments where system.web.extension is GAC'ed in the previous version giving you conflicts.

Comment: Thanks and if we upgrade to 3.5 then does it increase the webspace??

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Ajax .NET 2.0 downloads [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/archive/). (You can't use 3.5 assemblies for your 2.0 projects.)